# How to make an application detect if system time has changed in Linux

Tags: linux, time, notifications, date

I need to write a small application which needs to detect if the system time is changed by an another application/user and perform some action as soon as it is detected (maybe log the data that time has changed, along with info about which application/user changed it).

How can this be achieved?

1. I have good programming experiences in shell script, c and beginner level in python.
2. I don't need to know when it was changed, just need to know who/what changed it.
3. The system uses NTP to sync the time, but it is also possible for anyone/any application to change the time(for eg: using the simple "date" command as well).

Comment: You might want to add: What are your experiences in programming?

Comment: If you're going to log the time that `system time` is changed, how will you say *when* it was changed? What's your reference?

Comment: Is the assumption this test will only be needed during the current boot and does the system not have a time server?

Comment: I have updated the description with the information requested

Answer (score 4):

I think this article has an answer to your question: [Notify userspace about time changes](http://lkml.org/lkml/2010/9/16/405). But please note that the patch mentioned in the article is quite recent, so you have to check your linux kenel vesrion first.

If your kernel does *not* support userspace notification mechanism, then you can implement the following algorithm (in pseudocode):

```
time = gettimeofday()

loop:
    sleep 1 second
    new_time = gettimeofday()
    if (time_diff(new_time, time) > 2 seconds) then
       alert System time has changed by an external user/process!

    time = new_time
    goto loop
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note: time_diff should do abs() so there are no negative values.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use timerfd_settime() with `TFD_TIMER_CANCEL_ON_SET` ([`timerfd_settime(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_settime.2.html)):

```
  TFD_TIMER_CANCEL_ON_SET
              If this flag is specified along with TFD_TIMER_ABSTIME and the
              clock for this timer is CLOCK_REALTIME or CLOCK_REAL‐
              TIME_ALARM, then mark this timer as cancelable if the real-
              time clock undergoes a discontinuous change (settimeofday(2),
              clock_settime(2), or similar).  When such changes occur, a
              current or future read(2) from the file descriptor will fail
              with the error ECANCELED.
```

Answer (score -1):

[System Call Tracker](http://syscalltrack.sourceforge.net) do the same thing you want. You can use/modify that code.